# The 'Convention' badge and the Meta Stack Overflow migration

Tags: discussion, mso-mse-split, convention-badge

If I earned the [Convention badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188731#188731) once before the Meta Stack Exchange migration, will I earn it again if I get a post with more than two reputation points on this new Meta Stack Overflow site?

Answer (score 3):

The description of the [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/901/convention) is:

> 10 posts with score of 2 on meta.

You will note that it isn't "Every 10 posts...". The description doesn't say that the badge can be earned multiple times, when the description of badges that can be does say that.

In short - this badge can be awarded one time. That's it.

Comment: I didn't think I'd earn it ten times. I was mainly curious if the migration caused everything to reset. Normally there's one meta per SE network and that's it. But with this migration there have been two. So do you earn it once per SE network or once per meta?

Comment: You didn't lose the badge after the split and you shouldn't gain another one if you reach the criteria again on the new MSO. If you do, that'd be a bug.

Comment: You can only earn it once on any site that has a child-meta.

Comment: but, @Oded, is the badge only earned taking into account the specific child-meta of a site, or are the posts of meta.stackexchange.com  also considered?

Comment: @CarlosRobles - only the specific child meta of a site (so, you can earn it once per site whose meta you are active on). MSE doesn't have a child meta - one cannot earn the badge there.

Comment: clear and useful. +1